# How to make javascript link target to my iframe?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a iframe and there is a javascript function in it. Basically, I want to create an anchor tag to call the function and activate it in my iframe. Do you have any idea?

```
<p><a href="javascript:document.body.contentEditable='true'; document.designMode='on'; void 0" target="test">Edit Google</a></p>

<iframe name="test" src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
```

It is not working. Any idea?

Comment: This can't be solved using a single attribute like "target", you'll need to change the Javascript. Please show some code

Comment: I did not really understand your problem... SO you have a iframe and there, in the html of the iframe, there is the function you're talking about. You want to call it from the parent page of the iframe. If this is what you want I would tell you to explain the reason why you're doing so because this is not a very clear and standard way to do things... Also consider that, if you want to be xhtml 1.1 compliant, iframes shoud be treated with gloves... Anyway... please show some code, where the function in the iframe is located, I could be more helpful rather than guessing out :).

Comment: Actually the javascript I am using in the example above is universal. No matter what's the content in the iframe, you can actually just paste the javascript in the address bar and press enter. After that you can edit the page.

Answer (score 1):

I was searching around trying to find an answer, but I think it's easier if I just give you a link to this site that I found: http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/refs.php

Comment: A very good example is that. Let say I want to insert a javascript into google homepage. Basically, I just have to use my browser to open the address, http://www.google.com and type in the following javascript into the address and enter, then i can edit the page. "javascript:document.body.contentEditable='true'; document.designMode='on'; void 0". But now, I want to do something different, I want to do it this way. <iframe src="http://www.google.com" onload"javascript:document.body.contentEditable='true'; document.designMode='on'; void 0"></iframe>. Something like this but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that for obvious security reasons: one website can't and should never be able to control anything in other website.

If both pages are in the same domain there is a way, but different domains? Nope.

Instead of showing iframe you can try loading the external site with AJAX, parse the result and show your own form.